# I want to plot timevis in shiny apps was it is possible by taking input a file and then plotting timevis

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)
library(readxl)

timing <- read_excel("~/../Documents/timing.xlsx")



ui <- fluidPage(
  timevisOutput("timeline")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$timeline <- renderTimevis({
    timevis(timing)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a minimal reproducible example, in your case example data (you can use `dput(timing)` for it, then it's easier to help you, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to change `timing <- read_excel("~/../Documents/timing.xlsx")` to user supplied input file ? Have a look at https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/fileInput.html

Comment: My comment is" The user want to give a csv file as input and then generate timevis visualization

Answer (score 0):

You surely can, but as we cannot see what table your timing table created with read_excel looks like, I assume you get stuck on what data structure timevis requires. With this timing table your demo works.

```
timing <- data.table(
    id = rep(1:5),
    content = LETTERS[1:5],
    start = seq(as.Date("2021/09/04"), by = "week", length.out = 5),
    end = seq(as.Date("2021/10/19"), by = "day", length.out = 5)
)
```